# How do you display the server paths in Internet Headers in Outlook 2010 for an email?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

In Outlook 2010, displaying the Internet Headers is not showing the servers that the email passed through. How do you display this information? It was displayed in Outlook 2007 (and prior versions).

Answer (score 1):

Open the email and in the ribbon at the top, click the expand icon in the bottom right of the "Tags" section.  The Internet headers will appear in the properties box.